# Hadoop task doesn't finish - how to debug?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn

I have a 3 node Hadoop cluster. I run a mapreduce job - mappers on two of the nodes (name node and one of the datanodes) finish normally - but mappers on datanode2 start but time out after about half an hour. It is strange because of these facts:

1. same kind of mappers on other two nodes need 1 to 2 minutes to finish
2. all three nodes use the same hardware
3. the mappers on datanode2 take close to 100% on CPU, so they are in fact running.

Any idea what could be causing this or how to debug it?

Answer (score 0):

As per the Hadoop architecture you can check DataNode logs of DN-2 and if CPU utilization of DN-2 is 100% than sure your program will not work in DN-2.

Comment: The CPU is used by the mapper, it seems